# How to put an item in a context list that comes from related class?

Tags: python, django, forms, class

In a View context field I want to show a new entry from related class. Context list uses some type of format that I can't comprehend, so I need some help.

I have tried showing related information directly on the list, but I am missing attribute that should be provided to the template (I am talking about 'verbose_name')

```py
views.py:

class UpdateSimple(UserPassesTestRaiseException, UpdateView): 

    model = Subjects       

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UpdateSimple, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['readonly_fields'] = ['program', 'title', self.object.program.type]

        print(context['readonly_fields']) # For this I get: ['program', 'title', Fulltime]

models.py:

class Subjects(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=160, verbose_name="Title")  
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, verbose_name="Program")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Program(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=160, verbose_name="Program")
    type = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='Type')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want to get something similar in this part:

```py
context['readonly_fields'] = ['program', 'title', 'type']

        print(context['readonly_fields']) # For this I want to get: ['program', 'title', 'type']
```

On the page it should show result:

```py
form.instance - verbose_name
form.instance - value

Program: program1
Title: subjectTitle1
Type: Fulltime
```

Comment: I don't understand this question. If you want the string "type" in that list, why don't you put it there?

Comment: Adding 'type' to that list does not work. It is a specific django question, not python.

Comment: You should explain why that does not work, and how this is a "specific django question". What are you expecting to happen with that `readonly_fields` value? The only place Django uses that is in the admin interface, but this question does not have anything to do with the admin.